# Keycloak Resource not found when creating resource

Tags: authentication, authorization, keycloak

Im trying to create a resource using the keycloak protection API but when i try to create a resource with a POST to `http://{{host}}:{{port}}/realms/{{realm}}/authz/protection/resource_set`
body:

```
{
     "name":"Test Resource",
     "owner": "resource_ceo",
     "ownerManagedAccess": true
}
```

I get the return: Resource not found.

I'm making sure i get a PAT token beforehand with a POST to

```
http://{{host}}:{{port}}/auth/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

grant_type: client_credentials.

Why is it telling me the resource wasnt found, if im trying to create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add /auth/ in the POST endpoint so it needed to be:

```
http://{{host}}:{{port}}/auth/realms/{{realm}}/authz/protection/resource_set
```

Legacy version of the URL